# Find true positive, true negative etc in case of clustering location data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, precision-recall

I have been trying to evaluate a clustering technique. I understood F1 score is one of the effective methods to do that. As per the links I went through

```
F1 Score = 2 * (Precision * Recall) / (Precision + Recall)
```

Basically the harmonic mean of Precision and Recall. I also got what precision and recall is. And also that

True positive = correctly identified

False positive = incorrectly identified

True negative = correctly rejected

False negative = incorrectly rejected

But my problem is I couldn't relate this with Clustering.For example if I have the following scenario

```
Training Data = {(lat1,long1),(lat2,long2),(lat3,long3),(lat4,long4),(lat5,long5),(lat6,long6),(lat7,long7)}
```

And my clustering result is

```
Cluster1 = {lat1,long1),(lat2,long2),(lat3,long3)},

Cluster2 = {lat4,long4),(lat5,long5)}

Noise =  {(lat6,long6),(lat7,long7)}
```

How do I find True positive etc with my testing data in this case? I understood it in case of classification but I couldn't figure out in this case because of absence of the class.

**Update:**

I cant have classification metrics in my scenario. Since I am using location data the possible out comes I can find from the cluster formed are

```
Distance between two positions
Midpoint of the cluster
```

with which I can use the following internal evaluation measures

```
Davies–Bouldin index https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies%E2%80%93Bouldin_index
Dunn index https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn_index
Silhouette coefficient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)
```

But I want to proceed my further research on this towards true clustering. I understood that true clustering is making clusters manually and further evaluating clusters. I was wondering how are they evaluated? I cant find any articles or papers related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Precision and recall are **classification metrics**, and are not suitable for clsuter validation as is.

Furthermore, you need a **true clustering** to compare to. Classification data may not be adequate for this purpose, as classes may consist of more than one cluster, or classes may cluster themselves.

For evaluation of clusterings, please see *literature*. This is a too broad topic to cover here, spanning many research papers. For a starter, have a look at the **adjusted rand index**, ARI. This seems to be the most popular evaluation metric for clusters (external; i.e. if you have a ground truth).

Comment: That is not an algorithm. If you have e.g. synthetic data, then you can define a true clustering to compare to. But it is mostly useful to show that the cluster model agrees with your generator model.

Comment: Yup.. I don't find any source or examples of the way they are compared.
Example: True cluster has C1 = {1,2,3}, C2 = {4,5} and my algorithm has C1 = {1,2} , C2= {3,4,5}. What is the way I compare my algorithm in terms of correctness compared to true cluster?